# How to check if any of the value returned is 1 in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl in Windows and I have written the code in Perl for calling 2 jar files and i want to check if the value returned by any of these 2 jar files is 1.How can i implement this in Perl 
Code written to call the 2 jars(Sample1 and Sample2) in Perl

```
        my $cmd = "";
        my $res = "";
        my $cmd1 = "";
        my $res1 = "";
        $cmd = "java -jar C:/xampp/perl/bin/Sample1.jar";
        $res = qx/$cmd/;
        print "$res\n";

        $cmd1 = "java -jar C:/xampp/perl/bin/Sample2.jar";
        $res1 = qx/$cmd1/;
        print "$res1\n";
```

I want to check if any of these two jar files i.e If either of Sample1.jar or Sample2.jar has returned value 1.I'm using return statement in these jar files to return the value but I'm not able to take those values in perl and check if the value returned is 0 or 1 .Can anyone tell me what modifications should be made so that it would work properly.I tried using

```
if($res==1 || $res1==1)
{
$val =1;
print $val;
}
else
{
$val=0;
print $val;
}
```

But this didn't work.It's giving me an error 
Argument ""  isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at Sample1.pl line 30,  line 4.
Argument ""  isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at Sample2.pl line 34,  line 4.

Comment: Show us all of the actual output so we can see what the value is.

Comment: Note that `qx` (backticks) also return the linefeed (if there is one in the invoked program's output).  Thus it's common to use `chomp` on its return.

Answer (score 3):

`$res` apparently contains an empty string, so you are effectively doing

```
"" == 1
```

This is a numeric comparison, but the empty string isn't a number. You could use a string comparison

```
$res eq "1"
```

or you could handle the empty string specially

```
length($res) && $res == 1
```

Comment: (removed my comments about chomp-ing)

Comment: If I may --- **Congratulations** on 300k !!! (And mostly in the tag which is order of magnitude(s) less represented than some others!) :)))

Comment: @zdim, Thanks :) (About the chomping, it was a fair point, but I didn't want to spent more effort given the lack of clarity in the OP's post**s**)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this warning, you can use the function looks_like_number provided by the package Scalar::Util

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number); 
if((looks_like_number($res) && $res==1) || (looks_like_number($res1) && $res1==1))
{
 ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the values:

```
$cmd = "java -jar C:/xampp/perl/bin/Sample1.jar";
$response = `$cmd`

if ($response eq 1){...}
```

[See documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can't-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system()%3F)

**Or did you want to get the return code?**

[See documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

Snippet of this doc:

```
    my @args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
    system(@args) == 0
        or die "system @args failed: $?";

    if ($? == -1) {
        print "failed to execute: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
            ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
    }
    else {
        printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
    }
```